# Why this recursive function doesn't work in python

Tags: python

Program for recursively printing files and directory in python
    #!/usr/bin/env python

```
import os

temp_path = os.getcwd()
path = temp_path.split("/")
print path[-1]

def recursive(wrkdir):

    for items in os.listdir(wrkdir):
        if os.path.isfile(items):
            print "---"+items

    for items in os.listdir(wrkdir):
        if os.path.isdir(items):
            print "---"+items
            #following call to recursive function doesn't work properly
            recursive("./"+items)

recursive(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: `"./"+items` is only going to be the path to the folder in the first level of the recursion. Maybe `os.path.join(wrkdir, items)`

Comment: The same for `os.path.isdir`, you need to provide the full path

Comment: so what's the solution to this

Comment: let there are 2 folder named as fol1, fol2 and 2 files names as file1.txt, file2,txt in "xyz" dir. so if we run above prog from xyz folder then os.getcwd() will be /home/user/xyz. so at first wrkdir contain /home/user/xyz and after os.path.isdir(items), recursive will be called by /home/user/xyz/fol1. which looks perfectly fine

Comment: With the code above, the recursive function is called on `./fol1`, and not the full path. Print `wrkdir` if you want to be sure.

Comment: what about "recursive(wrkdir + "/" + items)" this then...this will definitely give /home/user/xyz/fol1

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware of `os.walk()`, which is the right approach for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 2):

You need to used the absolute file/directory path when checking for file/dir using `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir`:

```
import os

def recursive(wrkdir):

    for item in os.listdir(wrkdir):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(wrkdir, item)):
            print "--- {0}".format(items)

    for item in os.listdir(wrkdir):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(wrkdir, item)):
            print "--- {0}".format(items)
            recursive(os.path.join(wrkdir, item))

recursive(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def recurse(cur_dir,level=0):
    for item_name in os.listdir(cur_dir):
        item = os.path.join(cur_dir,item_name)
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            print('\t'*level+'-',item_name)
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            print('\t'*level+'>',item_name)
            recurse(item,level+1)

recurse(os.getcwd())
```